# Default role in CanCan with `roles_mask`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, cancan

I am trying to assign default role for new `users` with [CanCan gem](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan). Administrator can assign multiple roles to a user. In order to do this I added the following code:

```
# User's role handler (More information: https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/role-based-authorization)
# This will perform the necessary bitwise operations to translate an array of roles into the integer field
ROLES = %w[admin moderator user banned].freeze

def roles=(roles)
  self.roles_mask = (roles & ROLES).map { |r| 2**ROLES.index(r)}.inject(0, :+)
end

def roles
  ROLES.reject do |r|
    ((roles_mask.to_i || 0) & 2**ROLES.index(r)).zero?
  end
end

# Role Inheritance
def role?(base_role)
  ROLES.index(base_role.to_s) <= ROLES.index(role)
end

# Check the user's roles
def is?(role)
  roles.include?(role.to_s)
end
```

I want to define the default user role (which is `:user`) and I found this question: [Rails Cancan: Defining Default Role on Signup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37911060/rails-cancan-defining-default-role-on-signup)
. It says that I have to simple add `set_default_role` method:

```
before_create :set_default_role

private
  def set_default_role
    self.role ||= Role.find_by_name('your_role')
  end
```

But the problem that I am using a different approach of adding a new role. I have to store an integer instead of a string. Also, when you assign a role to the user, it stores an specific index to the `users table`. My idea was to add `default: 4` value to the `roles` column in the database but I've noticed that adding new roles to the database changes the `user index number`. In other words if `user role` was equal to 4, after update it will be 8 (for example).

The question is how to assign the default role to the user?

Thank you very much for your help and time!

Comment: Cancan gem is old. I think, you should use cancancan gem instead of cancan gem. -> https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan

Comment: @hamdi thank, I will switch then... anyways the approach is still the same :)

Comment: I think you should use enum values for user roles. You can find more details  in the below link for Role Based Authorization: https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Role-Based-Authorization

Comment: @hamdi probably you are right. I just followed `wiki` page on `CanCan`. Thank you very much.